# Erro Paginação CodeIgniter 2

Tags: php, codeigniter

Fiz um sistema em CI 2.0 e detectei um erro na paginação.
O script de configuração é o seguinte:

```
     $this->load->library('pagination');
   $query = $this->usuarioModel->obterRelacaoUsuarios($pagina);
            $config = array();
            $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
            $config['uri_segment'] = 3; // depends on how you passing your page number
            $config['base_url'] = base_url('usuario/listar');
            $config['total_rows'] = $qtdUsuario = $this->db->get_where('usuario', array('bol_excluido' => 'N', 'lotacao' => $this->session->userdata('lotacao')))->num_rows();
            $config['per_page'] = 10;
            $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination pagination-sm">';
            $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
            $config['first_link'] = 'Primeiro';
            $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['last_link'] = 'Último';
            $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

            $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
            $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';

            $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

            $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';

            $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

Observei que ao chamar a Sql :

```
 select * from usuarios LIMIT 10 OFFSET $pagina
```

Ao invés dele paginar de 10 em 10, as sqls montadas são:

```
select * from usuarios LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
 select * from usuarios LIMIT 10 OFFSET 2
 select * from usuarios LIMIT 10 OFFSET 3
```

Para resolver o problema eu adicicionei a seguinte lógica, antes de executar a sql:

```
 $pagina = ($pagina == 0) ? 0 : ($pagina * 10) - 10;
```

Assim a sql passa a ser:

```
    select * from usuarios LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
    select * from usuarios LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20
    select * from usuarios LIMIT 10 OFFSET 30
```

Minha dúvida é como arrumar esse bug sem ter que adicionar qualquer lógica e por que a variável    $config['per_page'] = 10; não está funcionando?

Answer (score 1):

Em seu sql no model, limite os valores enviados pelo `$this->uri->segment('segmento')` do CI e seu `$config['per_page']`.

Para facilitar a visualização usarei:

```
LIMIT X,Y
```

```
<?php 
//pagina_model.php

function obterRelacaoUsuarios($pagina = 'usuario');
    return($this->db->query(
       "SELECT * FROM $pagina LIMIT ?,?", 
          array(
              (is_null($this->uri->segment("3 ou 4 ou 5"))) ? 0 : intval($this->uri->segment("3 ou 4 ou 5")),
               $config['per_page'])
          )
    );
}
```